# Decoupling in the Linear Sigma Model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, higgs, symmetry-breaking, sigma-models

In Schwartz's 'QFT and The Standard Model' the Lagrangian for the linear sigma model is given by:

$$L=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu\sigma)^2+(\sqrt\frac{2m^2}{\lambda}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sigma(x))^2\frac{1}{F_\pi^2}(\partial_\mu\pi)^2-(-\frac{m^4}{\lambda}+m^2\sigma^2+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt\lambda m\sigma^3+\frac{1}{16}\lambda\sigma^4),\tag{28.12}$$

where $\sigma(x)$ and $\pi(x)$ represent fields, $\lambda$ is the coupling constant, $m$ is mass and $F_\pi=\frac{2m}{\sqrt\lambda}$ is a constant.

Why is the decoupling limit in the linear sigma model for mass of $\sigma$ fields and coupling $\infty$. For an $\infty$ coupling term shouldn't coupling be so strong that decoupling should not be possible. Also how does only $\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu\pi)^2$ is the only term that survives. When I do the calculation I get $\infty$'s that don't get cancelled.

Comment: A general idea in these mods is that in the large mass and coupling limit the these interactions/particles can only be excited at very high energies. I.e renormalization to energies far below the mass/couplings has the effect of forbidding excitations of these fields. As such the effect is essentially that they are locked to their vacuum expectation value without any fluctuations. As such you can effectively treat $\sigma$ as a constant such that the only remaining no constant therm is the $\partial \pi$ term

Comment: Show your work. Hint: eliminate λ in favor of the finite *F* and the diverging *m*. Now, as $m\to \infty$, the σ only enter as internal lines in amps only involving external π. See how the pinched/vanishing  σ propagators suppress effective π self-interactions and leave the super-heavy σ to just talk to itself in  a sector you never get to see/probe...